# Android out of memory error in List Adapter when loading images from resource using Bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I'm using image Cache and Bitmap to load images from local resource into a list Adapter but still getting out of memory error, I searched a lot for an answer but does not seem to find the right one, can anyone fixe my code please? Thanks in advance!

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.wraps_parisian,
                R.drawable.wraps_beiruti_2,
                R.drawable.wraps_berlin,
                R.drawable.wraps_cyprus_wrap,
                R.drawable.wraps_mexican_fajita,
                R.drawable.wraps_megabite,
                R.drawable.wraps_monaco,
                R.drawable.wraps_hail_caesar,
                R.drawable.wraps_philly_steak,
                R.drawable.wraps_cheezzy_blt,
                R.drawable.wraps_britannia,
                R.drawable.wraps_ranchero,
                R.drawable.wraps_ibiza,


     };

    LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> imageCache;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);

        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int casheSize = maxMemory / 8 ;
        imageCache = new LruCache<>(casheSize); 

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_item, parent, false);

        String[] names =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wraps_names);
        String[] prices =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wraps_prices);
        String[] ingredients =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wraps_ingredients);


        TextView item_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.items_name);
        TextView item_price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
        TextView item_ingredient = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ingredients);

        item_name.setText(names[position]);
        item_price.setText(prices[position]);
        item_ingredient.setText(ingredients[position]);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);


        Bitmap bmp  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mThumbIds[position]);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

        imageCache.put(position, bmp);

        Bitmap bitmap = imageCache.get(position);
        if(bitmap != null){

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the logcat

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter you are inflating a new view for each item in the list. This can be bad for performance and memory.It would seem like the viewholder pattern might help you here. You should also make sure only to do the decoding work if the bitmap in the cache is null.

```
   public class WrapsItems extends ListActivity {

    public static Integer[] wraps = {
            R.drawable.wraps_parisian,
            R.drawable.wraps_beiruti_2,
            R.drawable.wraps_berlin,
            R.drawable.wraps_cyprus_wrap,
            R.drawable.wraps_mexican_fajita,
            R.drawable.wraps_megabite,
            R.drawable.wraps_monaco,
            R.drawable.wraps_hail_caesar,
            R.drawable.wraps_philly_steak,
            R.drawable.wraps_cheezzy_blt,
            R.drawable.wraps_britannia,
            R.drawable.wraps_ranchero,
            R.drawable.wraps_ibiza,
    };


       public static class ViewHolderItem {
            TextView item_name;
            TextView item_price;
            TextView item_ingredient;
            ImageView imageView;
        }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories_item_list);

        listAdapter();

  }

    private void listAdapter(){
                setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, R.id.items_name,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wraps_names)));
    }


    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {



        LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> imageCache;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);

            final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
            final int casheSize = maxMemory / 8;
            imageCache = new LruCache<>(casheSize);
         }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
            String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wraps_names);
            String[] prices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wraps_prices);
            String[] ingredients = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wraps_ingredients);

            if(convertView==null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_item, parent, false);


                viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();

                viewHolder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_name);
                viewHolder.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
                viewHolder.item_ingredient = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredients);
                viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
                viewHolder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
            }


            viewHolder.item_name.setText(names[position]);
            viewHolder.item_price.setText(prices[position]);
            viewHolder.item_ingredient.setText(ingredients[position]);



            Bitmap bitmap = imageCache.get(position);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), wraps[position]);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);


                imageCache.put(position, bitmap);
            }

            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            return convertView;
        }


     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
android:largeHeap = "true"
```